# Required fields on request objects are not enforced

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I'm following through [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) from MS, but I'm not seeing the Required annotation get enforced on string fields.  It works on other fields, but not on strings.  I suspect it's because strings are nullable and something must just be converting the missing field to an empty string?  In the example below, I see the error on ThisField, but not on ThatField.  Any ideas on what needs to change?

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

...
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
public double? ThisField { get; set; }

[Required]
public string ThatField { get; set; }
```

Comment: try setting a min length may be?

Answer (score 0):

Update - for that specific ThatField, I was also using a custom validator, and it seems that both validators will get run.  So, even though the value isn't supplied, my custom validator was still getting run and failing due to a null value.  In other words, [Required] works fine on its own for That Field.

This works:

```
[Required]
public string ThatField { get; set; }
```

This does not:

```
[Required, CustomAttribute("valueA", "valueB", "valueC")]
public string ThatField { get; set; }
```